# Data format in excel not changing from 1/1/2015 to 1-1-2015

Tags: vba, excel

In Excel 2010 , I changed the date using the Format cells options, when I change it and click ok, it changes in the cell, but when i click on the formula tab its still 1/1/2015.

I am using VBA to read the data from this cell, i don't want different display on different PCs

Can someone help?

Comment: @pnuts A "formula bar." OP changed the number format instead of the settings.

Comment: Formula bar at the top of the sheet... when i change it to text it is giving out random numbers "42005"

Comment: @user3819867 what is OP?

Comment: Thing is, i can write a code for that but i am thinking there should be another way , a much simpler way

Comment: Ok , the problem is that i am not the original populator of that value, the sheet is given to me, now i have to extract that, the problem is that when i do it on different PCs it changes from 1/1/2015 to 1-5-2015 and vice  versa

Answer (score 0):

Changing a cell's format will change the way data is displayed in the cell, but not necessarily the way data is displayed in the **formula bar.**

*(there are some exceptions to this)*

Comment: Thank you , but i just now realised that , how to change it ?